# AWS IoT Policy for Shadows and Jobs

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, iot

I'm trying to create a policy that permits my things to read and update shadows, accept and run jobs and generally function permissibly in their namespace. I've gone through countless iterations of this and if I lock the policy down to anything other than "*" I'm no longer able to manually update the shadow in the console and have my devices accept the changes over MQTT.  My polcy is as follows:

```
{
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/events/job/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/events/jobExecution/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/jobs/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/events/jobExecution/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:DescribeJobExecution",
        "iot:GetPendingJobExecutions",
        "iot:StartNextPendingJobExecution",
        "iot:UpdateJobExecution"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

I realize there's some redundancy here but again I haven't been successful. I've also tried hardcoding `${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}` to a thing name with no success either. Any help would be appreciated and thank you.,

Answer (score 0):

This is working for me. Make sure that there is no other policy attached to your certificate that would override some permissions.

```
 {
  "Version": "2012-10-17",
  "Statement": [
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Connect",
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:client/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Publish",
      "Resource": [
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/delete",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/get",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/events/job/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/events/jobExecution/*",
        "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/jobs/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Subscribe",
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/accepted",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/rejected",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/delta",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/delete/accepted",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/delete/rejected",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/events/jobExecution/*",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topicfilter/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/jobs/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": "iot:Receive",
      "Resource": [
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/accepted",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/rejected",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/update/delta",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/delete/accepted",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/shadow/delete/rejected",
          "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}/jobs/*"
      ]
    },
    {
      "Effect": "Allow",
      "Action": [
        "iot:DescribeJobExecution",
        "iot:GetPendingJobExecutions",
        "iot:StartNextPendingJobExecution",
        "iot:UpdateJobExecution"
      ],
      "Resource": "arn:aws:iot:us-east-1:ACCOUNT:topic/$aws/things/${iot:Connection.Thing.ThingName}"
    }
  ]
}
```

Comment: This policy was too big by itself so I've split it in two and attached them to the thing group. Jobs seem to be working fine but the device still isn't responding to configuration changes made to the classic shadow.

Comment: are you sure you correctly subscribe to shadow topic?

Comment: Here's the Shadow policy, https://pastebin.com/RRkj2f5y. The shadows work fine when the policy is wide open.